# Excel VBA transferring numbers shouldn't round off decimals

Tags: excel, vba

I'm "copying" a row of a table to another location (range, not a table), using this method:

```
rDestination.value = TableRow.value
```

The last cell of the row is fraction of a dollar, such as $0.01925.  But when the value is copied to it's destination, it reads $0.02.

It's not just a format thing; I look inside the cell and it really does say $0.02.

(EDIT: The problem only seems to occur when the source cell is in currency format and displaying two decimals. That is, the actual value is $0.01925 but the cell is formatted $0.02.)

I've tried using this code both before and after the other one:

```
 rDestionation.cells(5).NumberFormat = "0.00000"
```

and also

```
rDestination.Cells(5).NumberFormat = TableRow.Cells(5).NumberFormat
```

But they don't work. (Not surprisngly, since it's not actually the format being affected).

Comment: Just wondering, did you have the chance to look at the answer I posted? No pressure, but I'd be interested to know if it did or did not solve your issue.

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't remember. You should have asked me back in February!  But I tried it today, and it does seem to work. A check for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.Value2` instead of `.Value`.

Here is a blog post that explains the differences between the 2 (namely when you are dealing with currency): https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/

As mentioned there:

> `.Value2` really should be the default, and is definitely the one
>   to use 99% of the time.

Comment: Good point.  I was aware of the issues with dates, but not with currency.  And your link doesn't really explain why the Currency value gets converted to **two** decimal places.  If that explanation is correct, I'd think it would get converted to **four** decimal places.  But using `.Value2` certainly works.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you are right, thanks for pointing that out! I've read that blog post long ago and just assumed it was explaining the problem here, but it seems like the main focus is on the case when you assign the value from the cell to a variable.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I made a comment under the blog post about this and the post was updated.